# Vary User Defined Runtime Attributes for Traits

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

I have created a view using `Storyboard` which has rounded corners. However I'd like to remove this for `iPhone`. I'm using user defined runtime attributes to get this done and I wonder if I can make a variation for `iPhone`.

[image]

Edit: I know I could do this in code, but it sounds silly since it's something visual and the storyboard file sounds like the right place to do this variation.

Comment: So are you trying to only use the runtime attributes for certain devices/platforms?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have those attributes only for some variations (like you can do with constraints) using "Vary for Traits"

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible at this point in XCode.  I tried manually copying the variation key into the userDefinedRuntimeAttributes key in the storyboard XML in XCode and the code seemed to be ignored and XCode removed it when I reloaded the storyboard.  It might be easier just to do this in code.

Comment: I thought so, but it sounds weird since those are properties for the view and you should be able to define them using the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension CALayer {
    var borderUIColor: UIColor {
        set {
            if UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone" {
                self.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
            }
            // do whatever you want
        }
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: self.borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

then use layer.borderUIColor to access the attribute.

Write an extension and redefine attributes, judge the device type in the set method would fix this problem! hope this fix your problem !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with Storyboards. You could just check for device type in code when loading that particular view and override the properties.

E.g.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone" {
        // reset attributes
    }
}
```